# better option to fetch data using api call, what to use: fopen, file_get_contents, and cURL

Tags: php

I am fetching data using API call.

I want to know which would be better option

**fopen, file_get_contents, OR cURL**

Kindly help.

**EDIT**
I have to make API call to remote system

Comment: The answer depends on the source from which are you trying to fetch this data. If it's a file on your local disk, then fopen( ) should do it; if it's an xml/html file somewhere, cURL is appropriate. Never heard of the other thing, sorry.

Comment: @Pete Wilson: oh, I believe that I have to wait for more answers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Depends on how much you need to tailor your request..

- `fopen` returns a `resource` which you must use to read the response manually
- `file_get_contents` does all of the reading for you (that you have to do manually using `fopen` and returns the resulting string
- `curl` is tailored *specifically* for network transactions (and according to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/555523/file-get-contents-vs-curl-what-has-better-performance) post, is quite a bit faster than `file_get_contents` and provides an API to set header values

All three allow you to tailor your request headers, but doing so with `fopen` and `file_get_contents` requires you to use a context callback to set the values with `stream_context_create()`.

Generally, `file_get_contents` seems to be commonplace when you need to do a simple `GET` on static data. `curl` seems to be standard when doing anything else.

Answer (score 1):

This depends on your usage, since you say api call, I'll guess this is not local...

If you're calling requests lots of times, use cull, has it has very good preformence.

If you are calling it little times, and Don't know how to use curl, then file_get_contents should suffice.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/555523/file-get-contents-vs-curl-what-has-better-performance

Answer (score 1):

This depends on your setup.

fopen and file_get_contents can only be used for getting data over a URL *if* `allow_url_fopen` is enabled. So you can't use this if your host has disabled this.

If that's the case, you can still use cURL. cURL also allows you to have a lot more flexibility when working with remote URI calls.

Answer (score 0):

You may be able to use `file_get_contents()`. It depends if your configuration has the [`allow_url_fopen`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/filesystem.configuration.php#ini.allow-url-fopen) setting turned on. If not, you won't be able to use `file_get_contents()` nor `fopen()`, as they both depend on this setting. In that case, you'd need cURL.

You won't need to use `fopen()`. Either you can use `file_get_contents()` instead, or you'll have to use cURL.

Comment: That's incorrect - you can use context in a `file_get_contents` to set the appropriate headers for a `POST` request. fopen *is* completely legitimate to use, but requires you to read in the data yourself. Having said that, I can't really think of a use case to use `fopen`, but it *is* viable.

Comment: @Demian Brecht Thanks for the info. I did not know that. I'll update my answer. As for `fopen()`, I didn't say it couldn't be used. I simply said you wouldn't need it if you could use `file_get_contents()`.

Comment: No worries :) There *might* be a use case to read in the data yourself, I just can't think of one offhand, which is why I didn't discount it in my reply. Otherwise, yeah - I agree with that part :)